# Get Checkbox Values using jquery

Tags: jquery

How to get the check box values from an datatable with pagination. I am getting the current page values only. Not able to retrieve values form multiple pages.

```
var records= [];
        $.each($("input[class=chk]:checked"), function(){
            records.push($(this).val());
        });
        alert("The selected rows are: " + records.join(", "));
```

Comment: push your html code to question too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer:

```
var checkbox_value = [];
        var oTable = $('#itemList').dataTable();
        var rowcollection =  oTable.$(".chk:checked", {"page": "all"});
        rowcollection.each(function(index,elem){
            checkbox_value.push($(elem).val());
        });

        alert(checkbox_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this way you can’t get other pages values beacuse they don’t exist in DOM. I don’t know you are using a plugin for datatable but there must be a function like datatable.getCurentData() which contains current values. Otherwise you should implement on your own logic in order to keep user inputs on every page changes.